# negate the effect of hover for one button in nav bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a navigation bar that has a black background with white text. The text changes to red when hovered over. however when the user is on the select page that specific background will change to red. however the hover over change the text to red. I want it so that when the user is on the home page, and they hover over the home button, the text doesnt change to red.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TL Custom Printing</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />


</head>

<body>

<div id="topbar">
</div>

<div id="navbar">
    <div id="navbtn">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" style="background-color:#F00;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="custom.php" >Custom Printing</a></li>
            <li><a href="store.php">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="logo">
    <img src="testlogo.png" alt="logo">
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

the CSS:

```
#navbtn {
    width:100%;
    Margin:20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center
}

ul {
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 2.25em;
}

li {
    width: 140px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

a {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding:8px 0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;

}

a:hover {
    color:#F00;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: So how do you assign the 'current' page bg-color? Not inline as you have indicated here...right?

Comment: Right now you have it done with inline CSS, which won't be responsive, but you can achieve this by using the `:active` pseudo class, most likely.

Comment: `:active` only works on mousedown...it doesn't indicate the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an active class to fix this easily: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/bAT79/)

```
<li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>

a.active {
    background-color:#F00;
}
a.active:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I also added your active tab background color into the `.active` class removing your inline style

Comment: +1. You can then re-use `class="active"` on any of your "tabbed" links for other pages so each page can be "active" when they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a:hover {
    color:#FFF !important;
    background-color:#000;
    }
</style>
```

In your html pages but your "home" so it will rewritte the main css sheet.